# Converting decimal based radix sort to bit-based

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I've finally got my decimal based radix sort to work, but want to turn it into one that sorts off of bits.

```
void LSD_radixSort (unsigned int * A, int size, int r)
{



     // Find the maximum number to know number of digits
    int m = getMax(A, size);

    // Do counting sort for every digit. Note that instead of passing digit
    // number, exp is passed. exp is 10^i where i is current digit number
    for (int exp = 1; m/exp > 0; exp *= 10)
        countSort2(A, size, exp);


}

unsigned int getMax(unsigned int arr[], int n)
{
    unsigned int mx = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (arr[i] > mx)
            mx = arr[i];
    return mx;
}

void countSort2(unsigned int arr[], int n, int exp)
{
    int *output = new int[n]; // output array
    int i, count[10] = {0};

    // Store count of occurrences in count[]
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        count[ (arr[i]/exp)%10 ]++; 

    // Change count[i] so that count[i] now contains actual position of
    // this digit in output[]
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        count[i] += count[i - 1];

    // Build the output array
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        output[count[ (arr[i]/exp)%10 ] - 1] = arr[i];
        count[ (arr[i]/exp)%10 ]--;
    }

    // Copy the output array to arr[], so that arr[] now
    // contains sorted numbers according to curent digit
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = output[i];
     i = 0;

}
```

without changing the parameters on my LSD_radixSort function, how would I go about converting it when r is my exponent for 2^r - 1?

Any suggestions at all would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to learn about [bitwise operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C).

What you need to know for radix sort is that 2^n is `1 << n` and that in conjuction with bitwise and `&` you can query if the the nth bit is set by `x & (1 << n) != 0`.

Comment: I forgot to mention the last snippet need not be that verbose, I just did so to try and make it clear what it was doing.